# print all variable of class list without using for statement in python

Tags: python, class

I put some classes(`wow`) in list `a`.
And I want to print the variable `num` of all elements of `a` without using for statement.
What should I do?

I want to(example):

```
[1,5,3,4,0] # Expected output
```

What I have tried:

```
import random as r

class wow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=r.randint(0,10)
a=[]
for x in range(5):
    a.append(wow())

print((lambda x: x)(a).num)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `for`?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `__str__()` method to your class:

```
class wow(): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.num=r.randint(0,10) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.num)
```

then by just printing:

```
print(*a)
```

you will get:

```
3 9 4 9 3
```

in addition, reading this [Link](https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions#:~:text=Python%20__str__(),is%20invoked%20on%20an%20object.&text=If%20we%20don't%20implement,calls%20__repr__()%20function.) might be good for better clue:

Comment: Oh, this is definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x.num, a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this, but you can use `map` with a lambda function.

```py
import random as r

class wow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=r.randint(0,10)
a=[]
for x in range(5):
    a.append(wow())

_ = list(map(lambda x: print(x.num, end=' '), a))
# prints:
2 8 0 6 5
```

You can also use a while loop and catch the `StopIteration`.

```py
g = iter(a)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(g).num, end=' ')
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You might harness `operator.attribgetter` for that task following way:

```
import operator
import random
class wow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=random.randint(0,10)
a=[]
for x in range(5):
    a.append(wow())
print(*map(operator.attrgetter('num'),a))
```

Output:

```
4 3 9 8 8
```